# Python Pandas Dataframe math (subtract, square root)

Tags: math, pandas

I get a Dataframe with with 4 columns and need a mathematical calculation with 2 of them and write the result in a new column.
The mathematical calculation is:

```
Exceldata.Blindleistung=(Exceldata.Scheinleistung - Execeldata.Wirkleistung)**(1/2)
```

This is how I tried it:

```
Jahresgang.columns = ['Zeitstempel', 'Spannung', 'Wirkleistung', 'Scheinleistung', 'Blindleistung']
Jahresgang.Blindleistung=(Jahresgang.Scheinleistung - Jahresgang.Wirkleistung)**(1/2)
```

The problem is that I don't now how to create a new column out of the result. I tried the way to create it before, but it did not work.

Comment: Does `Jahresgang['Blindleistung']=(Jahresgang['Scheinleistung'] - ['Jahresgang.Wirkleistung']).pow(0.5)` work?

Comment: No, i get the Error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'

Comment: Well that means your dtypes are not numeric you need to convert those first

Comment: Do you know a way how I can solve the problem? or another way to make the calculation?

Comment: Convert the dtype to numeric using `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` , see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects then the code should work as the dtype will be numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Exceldata['Blindleistung'] = (Exceldata['Scheinleistung'] - Execeldata['Wirkleistung']) **0.5
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." Thus you make your answer much more valuable and SO a better knowledge base.